# How to write a one-liner generator expression for an infinite stream of odd numbers from 1 to 99?

Tags: python, generator-expression

I am trying to write a one-liner Python generator expression that provides an infinite stream of odd random numbers between 1 and 99 inclusively.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why does it have to be a 1 liner? Have you managed to write it without the 1 line constraint? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Yes I wrote it without one line.

Comment: show your working.

Comment: its very easy! try yourself, if you know to write in one line then answer.

Comment: *Yes I wrote it without one line.* Show it, so we can build off of it, and have a demonstration of some kind of effort that you took in solving this problem on your own. StackOverflow is not a "do my work for me" website. Take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) . If you have the code ready, editing it in should not be a big task for you.

Comment: We made up this specific question for the Close.com Backend Engineer job application. A word of advice: if you can't figure this out quickly on your own without Stack Overflow then you're not a good candidate for the role.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random as rdm

g = (1+2*rdm.randint(0, 49) for r in iter(int, 1))
```

`rdm.randint(0, 49)` gives you a random int between 0 and 49. So `(1+2*rdm.randint(0, 49)` gives you a random number odd number between 1 and 99.

`iter(int, 1)` is an infinite iterator (which is always 0 and just used to keep the generator going).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.count()` to make infinite loop and `itertools.filterfalse` to filter values you don't need:

```
from random import randint
from itertools import count, filterfalse

f = filterfalse(lambda i: i % 2 == 0, [(yield randint(1, 99)) for i in count()])

for i in f:
    print(i)
```

Prints:

```
...
61
21
91
77
39
... and so on
```

**Version 2** (without itertools):

```
from random import randint

for val in (i for i in iter(lambda: randint(1, 99), 0) if i % 2 != 0):
    print(val)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this: (Python 3)

```py
stream = (lambda min_, max_: type("randint_stream", (), {'__next__': (lambda self: 1+2*__import__('random').randint(min_-1,max_//2))}))(1,99)()
```

Get randint with `next(stream)`.
Change min and max by changing the `(1,99)`.
Real 1 line! Can change min & max!

```
                           =========== Adding ===========
```

The version above isn't a strict generator -- it's another class. Version 2:

```py
stream = (lambda min_, max_: (1+2*__import__('random').randint(min_-1,max_//2) for x in iter(int, 1)))(1,99)
```

Use `next()` to get random odd number.
Change min and max by changing the `(1,99)`.